# What is the Noether stress-energy tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

The goal is to find the formula for the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), of mass-energy field.

The Poincare group's algebra generates it with 3+3+4 generators, the first 6 or the continuous Lorentz subgroup (Let's not mind the discrete elements for this matter), and if the other $4$ generate translation than it has to be the four-momentum as the generator.

A massive particle's action in terms of Lagrangian in Minkowski space depends only on the derivatives with respect to proper time.
The problem is I cannot get the Hilbert stress-energy tensor which is automatically symmetric, out of my path.

How can this tensor be formulated in order to see that stress-energy need not have something to do with symmetry or anti-symmetry at all. I don't mind a restriction to weak field, or to no gravity (SR) and a concrete simplest configuration is also enough.

How is it not automatically symmetric? That I don't understand.

I do understand why Hilbert's work on this is mentally unavoidable. :)

Comment: More on [symmetry of the SEM tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symmetry+stress-energy-momentum-tensor).

Comment: *How is it not automatically symmetric? That I don't understand.* The term $$\frac{ \partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi_\alpha)}\partial_\nu\phi_\alpha$$ in the [Noether stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress–energy_tensor#In_special_relativity) is not symmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Comment: @Ghoster that is the thing I wrote down actually before asking. Don't know why I did not see this.